# Создать пустой файл

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как создать пустой файл в Python? Если файл уже существует, сделать его пустым.

Понимаю, что можно с помощью

```
open(file, "w").close()
```

, но выглядит это не очень читаемо. Зачем для создания открывать и закрывать сразу? Есть какие-нибудь другие варианты?

Comment: Странный вопрос. Можете и не закрывать файл, если он пустой. Ну или так еще можно: `from io import FileIO; FileIO(file, 'w')`

Comment: @mkkik мне надо просто создать его, ничего писать туда не надо. Почему можно не закрывать файл?

Comment: Потому что он пустой, данные вы непотеряете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По аналогии с утилитой `touch`:

```
from pathlib import Path

Path('/tmp/file').touch()
```

Comment: Спасибо, так выглядит лучше

Comment: Только `touch` не сделает файл пустым, если тот уже существует.